# Navbar Menu Trouble shoot

Tags: html, css, menu, navbar, submenu

So I wanted to create the fixed nav bar on top of the page. Instead of creating nav bar with ordered list, I used the following approach:

```
<header>
    <div class="nav">
            <img src="images/logo_ab.png" alt="AurinBioTech Logo"/>
             <a href="index.html">Home</a>    
             <a href="#">About</a>    
             <a href="#">Team</a>    
             <a href="#">Science</a>      
             <a href="#">Need</a>     
             <a href="#">Pipeline</a>     
             <a href="#">Contact</a>     

     </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header .nav {
    margin-top:100px;
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:2%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;



}

header .nav a {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color:rgb(1, 1, 1);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Bebas';
}

header .nav a:hover  {
    color:white;
    background-color: #404040;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:0 auto;
}

header .nav a:active{
    background-color: #404040;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-decoration:overline;
}

header .nav img {
    width:260px;
    height:65px;
    padding-right:4em;
}
```

The reason I used this approach is because I wanted to use logo image next to the nav bar so it would align properly in the same line. Now the problem is that I need to add sub-menus under Science and Pipeline heading. Since I didn't use UL or LI, how can I add sub-menus under those heading.

OR, can you tell me any other way to create a NAV bar that shows the logo as well.
so it would be LOGO and MENUS on the same line.

Great thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the normal `ul li` structure.

If you set the height and line-height of top level `li` tags to be equal to the height of the image it will align the text to the center of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use a tool.
 CSSMENU where you can create a menu without writing the code.You can also change the code or add images as your wish if needed. There are some inbuilt images where you can use them too.

Comment: Can you share the website or the link for CSSMENU, that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Nabeel M :
\http://css3menu.com/
Enter your mail-id and then you can download a free version or premium either for mac/windows.
Paid version has many features .I suggest Premium.

Answer (score 0):

have a two column structure in your nav bar one column for the logo and other for the nav-bar options.

```
<header>
        <div class="nav">
                <img src="images/logo_ab.png" alt="AurinBioTech Logo"/>
        </div>
       <div class="options">       
          <ul>
           <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">About</a></li>    
           <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>    
           <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>      
           <li><a href="#">Need</a></li>     
           <li><a href="#">Pipeline</a></li>     
           <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>     
           </ul>
         </div>
    </header>
```

and
with css give them appropriate width and align them using padding or margin properties